# Communicate with custom usb slave device with DUE?

Tags: arduino-due, usb

I have a arduino due which i know has usb host mode. The usb library that comes with the due supports mouse and keyboard.

I have another usb device (diacnostic tool) id like to talk to, it use a:
USB Com Board Driver ( Multi-instance )
TI USBN9604
"Universal Serial Bus Full Speed Node Controller with
Enhanced DMA Support"
datasheet: www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/usbn9603.pdf

Ive also logged the raw byte usb traffic between windows and it when operating and would like to try sending some of those same calls to the device with the due.

Where do i start ?

Example Capture:

```
    000000: PnP Event: Device Connected (UP), 12.04.2015 09:14:51.390 (1. Device: USB Com Board Driver ( Multi-instance ))
The USB device has just been connected to the system.
000001: Bulk or Interrupt Transfer (DOWN), 12.04.2015 09:15:14.953 +23.562 (1. Device: USB Com Board Driver ( Multi-instance ))
Pipe Handle: 0x8639885c (Endpoint Address: 0x6)
Send 0x1b bytes to the device
 40 05 17 C0 00 09 02 00 AA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 16 06 12
```

Answer (score 1):

i found what i needed here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost
and
https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0